# When did Rus bring a korban?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, korban, book-of-ruth, masechet-kereitot

(Inspired by [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16170/1552).)

The gemarah in krisus [[8b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5152)-[9a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5153&size=1)] discusses the requirement for a convert to bring a korban (sacrifice) to enter into the community. If this is the case, how could Rus have converted in Moav or along the road to eretz yisroel (as is discussed by the commentaries)? Wouldn't she have needed to wait until she arrived at the mishkan (Tabernacle) in eretz yisroel to bring her korban and complete the geirus (formal conversion) process?

Comment: -1 The Korban is only neccasary in order to enter the mikdash and eat other kodshim. She could convert on the way for every other practical purpose, and likely did as there is no need to bring the korban immediately upon conversion.

Comment: that is not correct according to the tana kamah and from the hemsheich of the gemarah 9a.

Comment: Even the other hava amina is that lack of korban would prevent her from marrying a Jew. I still don't see why that means she can't have converted='became chayav in all mitzvot etc.' on the way. She doesn't even try to marry anyone until many months later.

Comment: Don't we say that the Korban is not Me'akev (hence conversion today is valid without it)?

Comment: @SethJ it's not me'akev when there is no way to bring it but was me'akev when there was a mishkan/mikdash

Comment: Source?(......)

Comment: you have to learn through the sugya but I believe Rabbenu Channanel and the Shitah Mekubetzes spell this out.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17118

Answer (score -1):

Rus lived at a time of "heter haBamos" ([when private altars were allowed to be used](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=zevachim&daf=112b&go=Go)) and, as such, she could have brought her korban on a private altar in Moav and converted there.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Wherever in the period of the Shoftim the story is placed (besides for the most well-known opinion - from Bava Basra 91a - that identifies Boaz with the shofet Ivtzan, there are a couple of others), during that entire era the Mishkan was in Shiloh - and bamos were prohibited during that time (Zevachim 14:6/112b). So -1.