# Why are modern conversions valid?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, korban, modern-times

I have heard that Rashi said that there are three requirements for conversion: brit milah; mikveh; korban in Beit Hamikdash. If this is true, why is it that this is not rendering modern conversions invalid until the Beit Hamikdash is rebuilt?

Comment: I was taught, but can't cite a source, that the convert's korban will be owed when the temple is rebuilt, but in the meantime we don't forbid conversion.  (Isn't this the same as all the other korbanot we'll owe when it becomes possible?  We don't say that atonement for transgressions is impossible because of the missing sin-offerings.)

Comment: See [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16851/when-did-rus-bring-a-korban) and the comment thread there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bamidbar 15:14 says that a convert must bring an offering "throughout your generations".  Sifre Zuta says that the inclusion of this phrase teaches that converts are accepted at any time. Haamek Davar states that the convert or their descendant must bring an offering when the Temple is rebuilt.

Comment: Does this mean that when the Beis HaMikdash is rebuilt, all of us might just go ahead and offer a korban, since there's most likely at least one convert up someone's family line?

Answer (score 7):

This question is related to [another](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16851/when-did-rus-bring-a-korban) and I believe the answers are the same. The sugya (discussion) is found in Talmud Bavli, Krisus [8b](http://images.e-daf.com/DafImg.asp?ID=5152&size=2)-[9a](http://images.e-daf.com/DafImg.asp?ID=5153&size=2). The resolution there is essentially that the korban (offering) is not m'akev (does not invalidate the conversion), which is learned from a gzeiras hakasuv (exegetical interpretation of a verse).