# May an individual become jew?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, conversion-to-judaism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for a Gentile to convert to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-it-possible-for-a-gentile-to-convert-to-judaism)

I was wondering to know if a person from non Jewish parent can become a Jew? Will he/she be recognized by other Jews as a Jew? Can he/she migrate to Israel?

Comment: Fast Furious, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here. It seems though that it has been asked once before here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7210/759. Try reading the answers there, and if you have further questions feel free to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) another question. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Some other posts on this site that you might find interesting: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12648/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16917/759

Comment: Good work team! Closed without mod intervention in 12 minutes!

Comment: @DoubleAA, *welcomed graciously, provided with useful references, and closed* without mod intervention in 16 minutes. Indeed, yeyasher kochachem!