# Proselytizing the covenant?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, noachide-laws, am-yisrael-jewish-nation

https://youtube.com/shorts/RuNO7R0885c?si=Fwc-02_yqnv-LfDi in this, rabbi Asher Meza of “Torah Judaism international” seems to claim that proselytization is not only allowed, but even a good thing to do. Now I understand that conversions should be welcoming and converts should be treated kindly and with respect, but Deutoronomy 32:8-9 seems to indicate that there is a difference between inheritance of Israel and the nations (which I understand to be referring to the torah commandments). Where does he get this Heter for? Especially since from what I understand non Jews who follow the 7 noahide laws have a share in Olam Habah.

Comment: It all seems a bit strange. [Other articles about Asher Meza](https://www.jta.org/2021/10/08/health/a-proud-boys-affiliated-rabbi-in-florida-is-offering-to-endorse-covid-19-vaccine-exemption-requests) also seem peculiar. Related question about the same man's ideas: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/was-judaism-ever-a-proselytizing-religion

Comment: Apparently this guy is pro-Christian proselytizing to Jews also. Avoid him like the plague. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l298_AMjdi0&t=149s

Comment: What kind of  proselytization?  Like walking up to a stranger on the street or in a parking lot and asking “Have you found Moses?”

Comment: I know the channel attacks a lot of people, and seems affiliated with crackpots like Yaron Reuven. But the words of Meza speak for himself. (And Shmuley Boteach and Slifkin have veered into heretical territory too. I'm not familiar with Friedman.)