# If a man converts to Judaism, does his already-Jewish son have to follow the custom his father decides to follow?

Tags: minhag, conversion-to-judaism

If a man converts to Judaism and follows Sephardic customs, and his son (who is Jewish-by-birth or has already converted) follows Ashkenazic customs, does the son have to follow his father and also observe Sephardic customs?

Comment: Why does the son have to be Jewish by birth? Would you think it’s any different if the son converted as well by a different Rabbi and therefore keeps different customs?

Comment: @DonielF If the mother is Jewish, then the son is Jewish. If the father is Jewish but not the mother, he is not Jewish and would have to either a) convert or b) remain a non Jew.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12716/when-if-ever-are-converts-still-related-to-their-relatives?noredirect=1&lq=1 The ger is not related halachically to his biological parents, even if the father happened to be Jewish. This would suggest that the answer is no.

Comment: @Shmuel Read my comment again. I’m well aware of what makes one a Jew. I asked if the father and son converted separately if this question would be any different; I’m trying to flesh out where the OP is coming from so I can gauge a potential answer better.

Comment: @DonielF I agree with what you are doing regarding the OP's question.

Comment: @Damila - that is the answer, and should be converted to such.

Comment: Has the question been asked why any son has to follow the customs of this father? My Rosh Yeshiva told me once that only community minhagim are automatically passed, and I don't think that would apply to an individual who grows up outside of any community.

Answer (score 2):

If the son was born a Jew then his non-Jewish biological father was not his halachic father and the subsequent conversion of this non-Jew has no effect on the son's customs.  Nor is this son required to show the traditional fatherly Kibbud Av to his mother's new husband if he were to marry her.  The son should ask his Rav / Rosh Yeshiva how to proceed (as one should in all cases).

Comment: Hi and welcome. How do you know this? We don't know who you are that we should trust you. Please let us know by [edit]ing your posts to include justification for your claims.

Comment: Welcome! Are you the Rabbi Moshen whose book is cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38085/)? You clearly know a lot about the conversion process; surely you'd be able to spend a few minutes longer in improving your answers by adding your sources.

Comment: אֲמַר לֵיהּ בְּגַיּוּתָן אִית לְהוּ חַיִיס נִתְגַּיְּירוּ לֵית לְהוּ חַיִיס - When they are gentiles they do have family lineage, but when they convert they do not have lineage, as they now belong to the family of the Jewish people and their previous lineage is disregarded.