# According to which Mitzva Boaz made a Yibum for Ruth?

Tags: yibbum-chalitza-levirate, book-of-ruth

According to which Mitzva Boaz made a [Yibum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yibbum) (Levirate marriage) for Ruth?

As I know, Yibum Mitzva is for brothers **only** (see Rambam [Yibum 1,1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Levirate_Marriage_and_Release.1?lang=bi)), while [Boaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaz) was a far kinsman [Ruth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_(biblical_figure)).

Comment: The Ramban on Bereishit 38:9 writes והיו החכמים הקדמונים קודם התורה יודעים כי יש תועלת גדולה ביבום האח והוא הראוי להיות קודם בו ואחריו הקרוב במשפחה כי כל שארו הקרוב אליו ממשפחתו אשר הוא יורש נחלה יגיע ממנו תועלת והיו נוהגים לישא אשת המת האח או האב או הקרוב מן המשפחה

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105047/170

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think he did Yibbum according to anyone? What do you mean by "which Mitzva"?

Comment: Of course, now I'm wondering why the Ramban cites חכמים הקדמונים קודם התורה when the story in the megillah took place after that.