# Should Ruth have insisted on Yibum and then chalitzah with the kinsman redeemer before marrying Boaz in Ruth 4?

Tags: halacha, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, book-of-ruth

The kinsman redeemer refuses to bailout Naomi and opts out giving Boaz the right to become the next kinsman redeemer.In the process of being the kinsman redeemer Boaz also consumates Yibum(levirate marriage)

Ruth 4:9 NIV

”9 Then Boaz announced to the elders and all the people, “Today you are witnesses that I have bought from Naomi all the property of Elimelek, Kilion and Mahlon. ***10 I have also acquired Ruth the Moabite, Mahlon’s widow, as my wife, in order to maintain the name of the dead with his property***, so that his name will not disappear from among his family or from his hometown. Today you are witnesses!”

Should Ruth have insisted on Yibum and then chalitzah with the kinsman redeemer before marrying Boaz?

Comment: How do you know Boaz performed Yibbum? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110090/759

Comment: Chalitzah only works prior to Yibbum. After Yibbum, one needs a standard get to be divorced.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, yibum itself is only with a living brother who is not married to a woman who would forbid such a marriage (such as a sister). Since both sons of Naomi had died, then neither Rus nor Orpah would have been subject to yibum.

That is why [Rus 4:13](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16456/showrashi/true#v13) says

> And Boaz took Ruth, and she became his wife, and he was intimate with
> her, and the Lord gave her conception, and she bore a son.

This shows that marrying Rus was just a regular wedding and was not part of redeeming the property.

As the [Malbim](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Rut/4.13#e0n6) says

> ויקח בעז – מספר שלא נהג כמיבם את אשת אח שאז יבמה יבא עליה ויבמה וקדושי
> כסף ושטר אין קונים רק עושים מאמר שהוא מדרבנן, כי יבום הזה לא היה אלא
> מצד המנהג לבד וקדש אותה בקדושי כסף או שטר שעז״א ויקח בעז את רות ותהי
> לו לאשה, קודם שבא עליה, ואח״כ ויבא אליה, ויתן ה׳ לה הריון עפ״י השגחתו
> הרתה תכף הגם שעם בעלה הראשון שהיה בחור לא ילדה.

This explains that it was not through Yibum, but was a marriage with money and a shtar. Had it been yibum, he would have just had relatins with her immediately. Indeed, even had Rus married the other redeemer, it could not have been Yibum or Chalitzah since we see that he just told Boaz to take her and did not do any ceremony (such as Chalitzah).